# MacBook Pro mid-2008 freezes or causes file system problem

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I have an old MacBook Pro (mid-2008, 15 inch). Apple replaced the main board and I upgraded RAM and replaced HDD.

When I use OSX on it, it freezes randomly and I have to reboot it.

I installed Ubuntu on it, it never freezes but sometimes it hangs for a while. And the other day, I copied many files to it over from network and the files are set read-only mode. I can't delete them even with sudo.

When I use the MacBook, usually it's very hot.

It might be too old to be useful now. However, I like it very much especially the keyboard (the metal one).

What do you think cause the problem? Is there a cheap way to diagnose it to find the problem part? I wouldn't mind spending 100 bucks to revive it.

Comment: If you're trying to debug it while it's running Ubuntu this might be better suited for http://askubuntu.com/ -- but as a general first step: what does `/var/log/syslog` say? Any warnings about disk errors? Have you run `fsck` against the disk to see if there are problems? It sure sounds like your disk or disk controller is dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might have faulty RAM. your macbook is not too old. I still use my white macbook from early 2008 with a hacked version of ML (not supported by hardware) with no issues. Try Memtest http://memtestosx.org/